# Gem cache is deprecated

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My setup: Rails 2.3.10, Ruby 1.8.7, Gem 1.6.2, Mac OS X

I generated a scaffold and got this warning

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.10/lib/rails_generator/lookup.rb:212:Warning: Gem::cache is deprecated and will be removed on or after August 2011.  Use Gem::source_index.
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.10/lib/rails_generator/lookup.rb:234:Warning: Gem::cache is deprecated and will be removed on or after August 2011.  Use Gem::source_index.
```

I don't intend to change lookup.rb since it is a Rails generator file, so how can I fix this warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deprecation warnings show us what will be changed/removed in future versions of rails

I found out an [article](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2006/12/4/how-to-turn-deprecation-warnings-off-in-rails) where it's shown how to switch this warnings off.

For a one stop, general, solution do:

```
ActiveSupport::Deprecation.silenced = true
```

The article has a couple of finer grained solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Dont't worry, since its a generator file, it will be updated till this date.